# Dynamic dividing a dollar game

Tags: dynamic-games, dynamic-optimization

> The question is a reformulation of an incomplete version.

Consider the following dynamic dividing a dollar game where agent 1 claims $x(t)$ of the dollar and agent 2 $y(t)$ ([paper](http://www.tau.ac.il/~fersht/Papers/1989%20Simultaneous%20Moves%20Concession%20Game.pdf)).

\begin{align}
&\max_{\{u(t)\}^T_{t=0}} e^{-rT}x(T)\\[2mm]
&\max_{\{v(t)\}^T_{t=0}} e^{-rT}y(T)\\[2mm]
\text{s.t. }& \dot x(t) = -u(t)\in[0,1-x(t)]\\
& \dot y(t) = -v(t)\in[0,1-y(t)]\\
& x(0) + y(0) > 1
\end{align}

where $y(T) = 1 - x(T)$ with $T:=\min\{t \in \mathbb{R}_{++} : x(t) + y(t) = 1\}$ and $r > 0$ is the time preference rate. Optimal feedback control is given by $u(t) = r(1-x(t))$ and $v(t) = r(1-y(t))$. This solution is somehow motivated by guess and verify.

- Can we obtain the solution by some first order conditions (e.g. maximum principle)?

### Transformation of objective function

I tried to somehow transform the objective function into a common functional.
Can someone confirm the following:
\begin{align}
&1 + \int^T_0{-re^{-rt}dt} = 1 + \left[e^{-rt}\right]^T_0 = 1 + e^{-rT} - e^0 = e^{-rT}\\
& x(0) - \int^T_0{u(t)dt} = x(0) + \int^T_0{\dot x(t) dt} = x(T)\\
\Longrightarrow \qquad& e^{-rT} x(0) + \int^T_0{e^{-rt}u(t)(r - e^{rt})dt} = e^{-rT}x(T)
\end{align}

- What next?

Comment: It seems something is missing: for any given r,T, x(0), you are maximizing x(T), which is done by setting u=0. Right?

Comment: Are you looking for a single $u$ or for a sequence of varying $u$'s along the $t$-index?

Comment: Ok, I see your points. Actually it's a dividing a dollar game, and $x(T)$ is the final claim of player 1 and $y(T) = 1-x(T)$ the final claim of player 2. He (player 2) maximizes $\max_v y(T)$ s.t. $\dot y = -v$ where $x(0) + y(0) > 1$ given. The markovian solution is given in the paper, however it is more or less guess and verify. I wanted to construct the solution by some first order conditions. Should I restate the entire question and delete this thread?